# XAMPP and Interbase: Call to undefined function base_connect() on Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, xampp, interbase

While coding a web aplication using php 7 on xampp using Interbase as database I keep getting the fallowing error message:

> Call to undefined function xxx\ibase_connect()

When trying to check if the interbase extension is loaded with `extension_loaded("interbase");` it returns false.

I already edited php.ini to enable php to work with Interbase changing this line: `;extension=interbase` to `extension=interbase` and even `extension=interbase.dll`.

I copied `gds32.dll` to `System32` and to `SysWOW64`.

The worse thing is that yesterday it was working!

Comment: so, if there interbase.dll file present in your PHP installation? if it is, see with SysInternals Process Monitor which folders PHP looks into to load that DLL

Comment: The php_interbase.dll interbase is present on PHP ext folder.
When using the command `php -m` it shows `php warning php startup unable to load dynamic library php_interbase.dll`

Comment: so, try to see in P.M. if php succeed or failed to find that DLL. Next thing would be to check they both are the same architecture (x86 or x64), then to use any dependency walker to check the dll's dependencies. For example, re "I copied gds32.dll to System32 and to SysWOW64." - did you copied THE SAME file to BOTH 32-bits and 64-bits folders ? Win64 Firebird installations have a utility to install gds dll system-wide, both x64 and x86 builds of it. Dunno about Interbase.